# Android ExpandableListView : set background color of selected item on click

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to set a background color for item when the user click on a child item in my `expandableListView`.

Here is the code :

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

@Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, long id) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(New_annonce_act_step2.this);
            builder.setMessage("Vous avez choisi la catégorie " +listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition) +", Continuer ?")
            .setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(New_annonce_act_step2.this, New_annonce_act_step22.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("titre", titre);
                    myIntent.putExtra("categorie", categorie);
                    New_annonce_act_step2.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                    finish();

                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });
            // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            builder.create();
            builder.show();

            return false;
        }

    });
```

Here is the ExpandableListView declaration in layout :

```
 <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/nouvelle_annonce_categorie"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:choiceMode = "singleChoice"
            android:listSelector = "@drawable/selector_categorie_item"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
```

And here is the coe of selector_categorie_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: And what wrong with your selector?

Comment: When i click on the item, background color is not applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first remove attribute:

```
 <ExpandableListView
                android:listSelector = "@drawable/selector_categorie_item" />
```

and also remove `background` selector from `ExpandableListView`.

Then in your child layout item put next attribute:

```
 <YourLayout
         android:background = "@drawable/your_selector" />
```

Maybe you need the `selector` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="true" 
     android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/exp_list_item_bg_pressed" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/exp_list_item_bg_focused" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
     android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/exp_list_item_bg_focused" />
    <item
     android:drawable="@drawable/exp_list_item_bg_normal" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Now, on click, only the grid of the expandableListView change of color. The clicked item doesn't change..

Comment: Try this
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/exp_list_item_bg_focused" />

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me:

```
expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view, int groupPosition, long id) {
            int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView
                    .getPackedPositionForGroup(groupPosition));
            parent.setItemChecked(index, true);

            return false;
        }
    });
    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            /*Toast.makeText(scanTemplateFragment.getActivity(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                            + " -> "
                            + expandableListDetail.get(
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            int index = parent.getFlatListPosition(ExpandableListView
                    .getPackedPositionForChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
            parent.setItemChecked(index, true);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

and set background from list_item.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvListItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/row_highlighter"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

row_highlighter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    <item android:drawable="@color/std_color_1_bright" android:state_activated="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </selector>
```